# TWIG Can't access to Object property

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, twig

I have the next object in TWIG:

```
{{dump(profile.profileTagOne)}}

Tag {#2306 ▼
  +__isInitialized__: true
  #id: 1
  #name: "This is my name"
  #slug: "this-is-my-name"
  #native: true
  #perfil: PersistentCollection {#2307 ▶}
   …4
}
```

If I show the var **profile.profileTagOne** I got the name, but If I try to access to the id i got the error: *Impossible to access an attribute ("id") on a NULL variable ("") in..., I'm trying to access by* **profile.profileTagOne.id**

Any idea?

Comment: Are you sure there is no some `{% for %}` look around that and you're trying to access some other object?

Answer (score 3):

Per the documentation for the [VarDumper component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/var_dumper/introduction.html), attributes prefixed with a `#` are `protected`, which means you can't access them directly.

You either need to change the visibility of `Tag::$id` or write a public-visibility getter.  Does `Tag` have a `getId()` method?